How to make decisions when statistics provide completely different conclusions when viewed from different perspectives?
One can look at a statistic from two different perspectives and come to two completely opposite conclusions.
Consider how Radon gas in homes contributes to lung cancer.
The danger is linearly proportional to the concentration in the air:

A lifetime exposure of 300 Bq/m³ of radon gas will cause 15 deaths per thousand.
A lifetime exposure of 150 Bq/m³ of radon gas will cause 8 deaths per thousand.
A lifetime exposure of  75 Bq/m³ of radon gas will cause 4 deaths per thousand.


An HVAC company can install "heat recovery ventilators" that will continually refresh the air in the house, typically reducing the ambient concentration of Radon by about 50%.
At 5–10 thousand dollars, plus ongoing increased heating and cooling costs, it's expensive, but cutting one's chances of developing lung cancer in half sounds like a good thing to do.

Halving the concentration from 300 to 150 increases one's survival rate from 98.5% to 99.2%, and halving it from 150 to 75 increases the survival rate from 99.2% to 99.6%.
Paying that much money to improve one's already very good chances by less than ½%, just doesn't seem worth it.


Both arguments are based on exactly the same statistical values, and each is equally valid.
The evidence is hard and objective, but deciding which way to look at it is very soft and subjective.
Is there a name for this seemingly paradoxical phenomenon, and is there a mathematically rational way of resolving it?

Note that the above situation is given only to serve as an example. Please don't dispute the values it uses or that it is about radon gas rather than some other factor.

I don't think you can answer this question without being much more specific about costs and benefits; that is, this is a decision-theoretic question rather than a statistical one. If you wanted to formalize it, even without considering tradeoffs between years of life and other values (e.g. quality of life), you would need to consider how to allocate $$ across different costs (radon mitigation, healthier diet, preventive medical treatments, avoiding other toxins/pollutants ...) to maximize lifespan ...

This is very common, e.g. for quality improvement projects on a production line. Say that I cut my reject rate in half; worth doing right? But my reject rate was already pretty good, say 4 parts per million (ppm; ~ 6sigma-ish), and now it is 2ppm. My yield was improved by .0002%. Worth the $$? The problem is the use of relative terms (% change) vs. absolute terms (yield, or odds of dying from radon). For some related humour, check this xkcd cartoon https://xkcd.com/1252/ or this one https://xkcd.com/1102/. A big change in something very small is still very small...

@BenBolker says "I don't think you can answer this question without being much more specific about costs and benefits". It's only an example; the values are irrelevant to what I asked. One perspective says "It's a no-brainer; just do it." while the other says "It's not worth worrying about; forget about it". Both are logically correct, but they can't both be right. Another example: If I buy a second lottery ticket, I double my chances of winning (good; do it); If I buy a second lottery ticket I decrease my chances of losing by a ten-thousandth of a percent (useless; don't waste your money).

@RayButterworth How much money are you wasting? If it’s so little that the lottery has a positive expected value upon buying that second ticket, maybe it’s not such a waste!

@jginestet, so you're saying both views are inappropriate, as the real comparisons should be whether it's worth spending 5–10 million dollars to prevent 7 deaths (for the 300⇒150 case), and if it is, is it worth spending the same amount for 4 deaths (the 150 ⇒75 case)?

Never mind statistics; there's a rather fundamental sense in which a description of the world can't possibly tell you what to do (David Hume's is-ought distinction). To know what action to take, you have to formalize what it is you actually care about. The classical approach to this is something like expected utility theory, where you weigh the expected lifespan increase from installing the ventilator against the cost of the installation (which of course requires other assumptions like the monetary value of an increase of lifespan at the margin)

@RayButterworth, exactly.  It is a cost/benefit trade-off, which can depend on many factors. In your example, you have to add to this the highly subjective, and ethically debatable issue of assigning $$ to the life (or added lifespan) of humans. My yield example is simpler, on purpose, to high;ight how one would approach this issue w/o the ethical "bagage".
